# Equivalence of probabilities involving intersections and compliments

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have two events, *A* and *B*.

Is P(*B*) equivalent to P(*A*∩*B*) + P(*A*<sup>c</sup>∩*B*)?

Based on my venn diagram drawing, I am pretty sure those two statements are equivalent:[image]

The Red section should represent P(*A*∩*B*), and the Blue I believe represents P(*A*<sup>c</sup>∩*B*). If I am correct, then naturally the sum of these two probabilities is the P(*B*).

However, I would like to be certain of this. It is difficult to find this sort of specific equivalence on Google search.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say equal, not equivalent. Your expression is correct.

Comment: thanks for the advice and sanity check; I edited the post.

Comment: You are welcome. Venn diagrams are a helpful device! It can be done "algebraically" but that process is less intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it algebraically, notice that $B$ admits the next decomposition:
$B=B\cap\left(A\cup A^{C}\right)$. Because $A$ and its complement are a partition for the Sample Space. So

$P\left(B\right)=P\left(B\cap\left(A\cup A^{C}\right)\right)$=
$P\left(\left(B\cap A\right)\cup\left(B\cap A^{c}\right)\right)$=
$P\left(B\cap A\right)+P\left(B\cap A^{C}\right)$

Based on the fact that $\left(B\cap A\right)$ and $\left(B\cap A^{C}\right)$ are disjoint.

Comment: excellent, good answer! I did not realize that *B* could be distributed over *A*∪A<sup>c</sup> like that.

Comment: Happy learning!